# Logic apps - Get response time of a http request

Tags: azure, ping, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Logic apps to ping our website every 10 minutes. I would like to know how to get a response time of that call to make sure the website is now slow.

Currently i am doing this

1. Recurrence (Every 10 minutes)
2. Get Current Time
3. Http GET Call
4. Get Current time 2
5. Difference of (Current time 2  - Current time)
6. Condition to see if it is greater than threshold.

This looks like a not clean solution. Wondering if there is a easier way to get the time / latency of that HTTP call in step 3

Comment: you can expose a healthcheck route in your app and use pingdom / application insights or another tool to "ping" and provide you the response time / slow performance warning

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio .. i am trying to check the status of a 3rd party website - so cant really modify the app. any suggestions without it?

Comment: pingdom should work for that

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc, with the connector you're using is not possible to get response time. You'd better use Azure Functions for that. More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure application insights for this kind of situation it's the best and optimal solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview